# Extracting pages title from PDF document

Tags: python, pdf, text

I'm at my very beginning of my coding adventure.
I need to extract the pages/tab names from big PDF document (350 pages). Image attached.
I tried with pdfminer because theoritically these names are also included on PDF pages, but to get them, I need to set  some rules. It would be easier to get these names from tabs. Is it possible? Any tips what should I use?

Comment: maybe you can find it in the metadata of the pdf if it was created properly _and_ if its author cared about such things

Answer (score 0):

You can use PyMuPDF which is a high performance Python library for data extraction, analysis, conversion & manipulation of PDF (and other) documents. Like this,

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF library

ref_pdf = fitz.open(r"C:\any.pdf") # open a document
page_count = ref_pdf.page_count

for i in range(page_count): # iterate the document pages
    page = ref_pdf[i]
    page_text = page.get_text() # get plain text encoded as UTF-8
    print(page_text)
```

page text will have All the text from each page including pages/tab names.

Refer: https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/

Comment: thank you very much, that would help a lot :)

Comment: Is there any option to extract just a tab/pages names?  
Or need I set some conditions i.e re.compile(...)?